# Raspberry pi 4 - recording with 4 mini usb microphones - arecord

Tags: microphone, arecord

Im using mini usb microphone for recording audio. The sound is not good so i trying connect 3 more (total 4) mini usb microphones. I tried
`arecord --device=hw:1,0 --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -V mono -c1 voice.wav`
so how i can record with 4 microphones? What config file and how i must edit it? :(

Comment: so, do you want to record to 4 different files one from each of the 4 microphones, or are you trying to record from 4 microphones into one file?

Comment: I want record from 4 microphones into one file

Comment: so what devices are available to record from? e.g. you've shown `hw:1,0` - what else is there?

Comment: here's some alsa documentation that will help - it's using two stereo input devices to create a virtual 4 channel device ... but you should be able to extrapolate how to use 4 mono input devices to do the same (you'll have slave a,b,c,d with 1 channel each and the bindings channel will all be channel 0) https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#Virtual_multi_channel_devices

Answer (score 0):

Based on *documentation* I found [here](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#Virtual_multi_channel_devices) - extrapolating for 4 mono real devices as opposed to 2 stereo real devices as per the documentation

add this to .asoundrc

```
pcm.multi {
    type multi;
    slaves.a.pcm "hw:1,0";
    slaves.a.channels 1;
    slaves.b.pcm "hw:2,0";
    slaves.b.channels 1;
    slaves.c.pcm "hw:3,0";
    slaves.c.channels 1;
    slaves.d.pcm "hw:4,0";
    slaves.d.channels 1;
    bindings.0.slave a;
    bindings.0.channel 0;
    bindings.1.slave b;
    bindings.1.channel 0;
    bindings.2.slave c;
    bindings.2.channel 0;
    bindings.3.slave d;
    bindings.3.channel 0;
}

ctl.multi {
    type hw;
    card 1;
}
```

then you can

```
arecord --device=multi --format S16_LE --rate 44100 -c4 voice.wav
```

I can't check the above, I only have two such dongles, but excluding c/d slaves does allow me to record stereo from 2 x mono inputs - so I imagine this should work just fine

I'm also assuming the device ID's as being hw:1,0 -> hw:4,0 - but that seems to be a safe bet

I also excluded the pcm.ttable etc stuff as you didn't mention JACK at all